# Get list of types in dataframe columns, skipping NaN cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this dataframe:

```
df

col1    col2        col3     col4
  1       apple     NaN      apple
  2       NaN       False    1.3
  NaN     orange    True     NaN
```

I'd like to get a list of all types in each column, excluding the NaN/null cells. Output Could be as a dictionary like this:

```
{'col1': int, 'col2': str, 'col3':bool, 'col4': [str,float]}
```

I've gotten as far as creating a dictionary that outputs all the strings in each column *including the NaN values*. I'm not sure how to exclude the NaNs.

```
output = {}
for col in df.columns.values.tolist():
    list_types = [x.__name__ for x in df[col].apply(type).unique()]
    output[col] = list_types
```

The code above would get me almost what I want, but with a bunch of extra "float"s for the NaNs:

```
{'col1': [int,float], 'col2': [str,float], 'col3':[bool,float], 'col4': [str,float]}
```

Answer (score 0):

For excluding nan, do

```
df = df.dropna()
```

Then for getting data types:

```
df.dtypes
```

Comment: .dropna() would drop all the columns in this case, making df an empty dataframe. also, dtypes is different from apply(types)

Answer (score 0):

In the below approach, what I have done is that I extracted the Non-NAN items to a list and then found the dtype of the remaining list:

```
#initialize the empty column
output={}

#loop over the columns
for column in df:
  a=[x for x in df[column] if str(x)!= 'nan'] 
  output[column]=type(a[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `stack`, this will drop the `NaN` , then we do `groupby` + `unqiue`

```
df.stack().apply(lambda x : type(x).__name__).groupby(level=1).unique().to_dict()
{'col1': array(['float'], dtype=object), 'col2': array(['str'], dtype=object), 'col3': array(['bool'], dtype=object), 'col4': array(['str'], dtype=object)}
```